# Extending PKRevealController with UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer's

Tags: ios, objective-c, subclassing

I'm trying to use PKRevealController, it comes with `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on the front view controller so a panning would reveal Left view controller. I wan't to have this panning only when the swipe comes from Edge of the screen. I know I have to use `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` instead of  `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.  And I also need the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on front view controller when the left view controller is being shown, so that user will be able to swipe the front view controller back.

There is no easy for doing this so I decided to subclass PKRevealController and add new `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` and override some of the methods to this effect. But none of the methods which handle gestures are declared in class extension. So I'm not able to access them in my super class.

Finally decided to make changes in the source code of PKRevealController. I made all the changes and it is working as I wanted. **But I know that we should only subclass third party frameworks and extended their functionality and not by changing source code directly**. But I'm not finding any work around.

Is there any work around with out making changes in PKRevealController source code itself. Any suggestions would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, I had the same problem a few weeks ago. I didn't find an easy and completely clean way to solve this, but I did manage to work around by subclassing `PKRevealController` and being moderately "invasive" (which doesn't mean it can't break with a future update of the lib).

So, what I did is to create my own `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` and store it in a property (everything here is in my `PKRevealController` subclass):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *screenEdgePanGestureRecognizer;
```

in `init`:

```
// use screen edge pan gesture recognizer instead of normal built-in pan gesture recognizer
self.recognizesPanningOnFrontView = NO; // disable built-in pan gesture recognizer

self.screenEdgePanGestureRecognizer = [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                        action:@selector(didRecognizePanGesture:)];
self.screenEdgePanGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
self.screenEdgePanGestureRecognizer.edges = UIRectEdgeLeft;
```

Notice, that the action selector (`didRecognizePanGesture:`) is implemented by the superclass.

Then, in order to install my own gesture recognizer rather than the built-in one, I've overwritten `updatePanGestureRecognizerPresence`:

```
// overwritten to use our custom screen edge pan gesture recognizer!
- (void)updatePanGestureRecognizerPresence
{
    if (![self.frontView.gestureRecognizers containsObject:self.screenEdgePanGestureRecognizer]) {
        [self.frontView addGestureRecognizer:self.screenEdgePanGestureRecognizer];
    }
}
```

And since we are accessing some non-publicly declared stuff of `PKRevealController` (as you have noticed yourself), we need to make it visible (before your `@implementation`):

```
// make private superclass stuff visible to be able to use a screen edge gesture recognizer
@interface PKRevealController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) PKRevealControllerView *frontView;
- (void)didRecognizePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer;
@end
```

It works very well and it's the best approach that I could find without having to fork `PKRevealController` itself. It's definitely a bit fragile, but since I have the full control over when I upgrade `PKRevealController` that's ok for me.

The best thing you could do, of course, would be to fork `PKRevealController`, implement the option to use a screen edge recognizer (or make the whole gesture architecture in there more extensible) and submit a pull request. :-)

Comment: I have used the same approach to achieve this functionality. But the problem with by modifying his source code is , I don't have control over when someone might update the project. And the development on the project is year back. I moved on to different App drawer, https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController . This is providing all the functionality out of the box. It also comes with nice animations. :) I would say give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to `MMDrawerController`, looks quite nice and well architected. Anyways, I just wanted to point out again that I didn't "modify" any of the code `PKRevealController`, I did everything in my subclass. But of course, it's quite tightly tied to the inner workings of the library, and thus a bit fragile.

Answer (score 0):

I found another app drawer which is being currently developed and providing all great features from edge panning to animations. Here is the link to the https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController . It don't take too much time to upgrade your project to use new DrawerController or Reveal control.

The main thing is extending this framework to add more functionality is easy and the team is actively contributing to project.